# Scorm12courseframe.aspx - Not Found?

Tags: scorm

I had a "SCORM Course" handed to me that supposedly will play...but it does not.  When I try to load it up in our LMS it give me the following error:

"The page cannot be found"

Here's the URL:

/Kview/CustomCodeBehind/base/courseware/scorm/scorm12courseframe.aspx

I've tried to search the contents of the course, etc. but I don't see this page anywhere.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Ann,
Thats an ASP.NET page.  Normally not deployed in a Shareable Content Object.  Only thing I can make out is its possibly affiliated with "learn port" which is possibly a LMS or a portal using another .NET based LMS.

That page would appear to be the page that houses the content aka frame.  But it sounds more like a configuration issue rather than something with the content.  Its possible someone else will recognize the .NET page and be able to link it back to a LMS project.

Comment: That is definitely a page from an LMS. Just google "kview customcodebehind" to see several other educational portals that use that path. If you can’t find that URL on your system, then the SCORM course itself may have a hardcoded links to it.